# Clip path not supporting in wagtail template

Tags: svg, django-templates, wagtail, clip-path

I purchased one template and I am using that for my website based on Wagtail. The clip path property works fine in the purchased template but when I am using the same code in wagtail template it simply doesn't seem to work.
Except this clipping, all other items works fine. All the static files are properly linked, there is no issue.

**The code**

```
<div class="image-box">
    <svg  version="1.1" class="Layer_1 svg-sprite" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="854" height="632">
      <clipPath class="clip1">
        <use xlink:href="#shape-one" />
      </clipPath>
      <g clip-path="url(#shape-one)">
        {% image page.dyn_team_img original as dyn_team_img %}
        <image width="854" height="632" href="{{ dyn_team_img.url }}" alt="{{ dyn_team_img.alt }}" class="image-shape">
        
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Please someone help me to identify what I am missing.

Comment: There's no element with id="shape-one"

Comment: I didn't understand. Could you explain a little? I have no concept in this!! @RobertLongson

Comment: The SVG appears to be wrong, you should correct it. There are various online SVG primers that will help you get the concept/syntax of SVG. We can't explain everything here from first principles though.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Django or Wagtail. The SVG use references an element with id=shape-one. And it is likely that that element is not available in your html. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use